# Save user reorder of tabs in tabbed application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

As I have been developing a tabbed application inside of Xcode using swift4 I noticed that once you have enough tabs and click on more it gives you the option to reorder the tabs. However they reset when I close the app. Any way I can save the order they change the tabs to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass your TabBarController using the next code

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self

        restoreOrder()
    }


    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didEndCustomizing items: [UITabBarItem], changed: Bool) {

        let order = getCurrentOrder()
        saveOrder(order: order)
    }

    private func getCurrentOrder() -> [Int] {

        var order: [Int] = []

        if let controllers = self.viewControllers {
            for controller in controllers {
                order.append(controller.tabBarItem.tag)
            }
        }

        return order
    }

    private func saveOrder(order: [Int]) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(order, forKey: "TabBarItemsOrder")
    }

    private func restoreOrder() {

        guard let order = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TabBarItemsOrder") as? [Int] else { return }

        var reorderedControllers: [UIViewController] = []

        if let controllers = self.viewControllers {
            for tag in order {
                for controller in controllers {
                    if controller.tabBarItem.tag == tag {
                        reorderedControllers.append(controller)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        self.setViewControllers(reorderedControllers, animated: false)
    }

}
```

Set a tag for each viewController tab bar item managed by your Tab bar controller.

[image: tabs]